# What's the best way to beat Shao Kahn in Mortal Kombat?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

I'm playing the new Mortal Kombat and I am having trouble beating Shao Kahn in the story mode with Liu Kang.  Does anyone have tips and strategies on how to beat him?  He's very cheap.

Comment: Wait till you have to fight him with Raiden....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the bike kick and the flying kick every time he taunts. Throw in some upper cuts when he blocks the flying kick.

Comment: I finally cheesed him with low fireball and flying kick him if he comes too close.

Answer (score 5):

I think I found an even easier way:

Jump backwards, so there is a full screen distance between you and Kahn, then do the high fireball (back, forward, X) over and over again. After a few fireballs you will feel the rythym.

In this state, Kahn will only do three things:

```
a) block, you will only damage him slightly
b) throw a lance, if your rhythm is good, he will be interrupted, otherwise you will be damaged, but he won't do anything else if you continue fast enough
c) taunt, free damage
```

Cheap, but works.

Comment: Yea, cheap is pretty much the only way to beat him.